# Converting a base64 encoded bmp image to it's pixel values in python backend

Tags: python, typescript, html5-canvas, backend

As the question says, i need a way to decode a base64 image into the pixel values of that image. I tried using opencv for imdecode, and that's pretty much all i found about this.

The reason i want to do it is because i am writing a backend api, which receives a base64 encoded image from a web application (written in TypeScript if that's needed, from a  object) and then in python i want to parse it's pixel values to do some computation, like see what's the average color of the image.

The problem is that the data isn't sent just as pixels probably, it's a strange format and i don't know how to decode it.

Here is an example base64 image:

**EDIT**
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAh0lEQVQ4T+3TMQ6AIAwF0PZIbIxwcljZuFENJhiDrX4imzKT109bWESEFh7+wdfdvO0hM18KPM0QAhtyxu/Q6Sl32EKnwForOecohEApJbXfMLjsyeNglgzF2iUNV5/cUllJSinkvT9qjPemwSblnCnGuKMwiH4ZCOxYT2GtiFYUXhs08QfBDdNTgsUZ/lOUAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC==

It can be decoded in browser decoders and it also shows the image properly, i just can't decode it so that i can iterate through the pixel values.

Comment: @martineau that was my bad, i copied the string wrongly

Comment: When I try to read the updated base64 decoded data into PIL it says `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x002767D0>` so it's not the data friom a BMP format image file (or any other recognized format).

Comment: @martineau i don't really know what format it is but it should be a bmp image. For encoding it i used the canvas.toDataUrl() function from typescript, to take an image from a canvas and convert it into a base64 string. As params i had to give it the format, and i tried multiple ones but for the 2 images in this thread i used "image/bmp" as a parameter for the function

Comment: This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) says `toDataURL()` returns a "[data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)", which is not the same thing as the data of an image file — which is what is needed here I believe.

Comment: FWIW, I tried a couple of the base64 encoded [examples of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples_of_use) in the Wikipedia article on data URIs, and they all decoded successfully — so the problem may be simply how you are extracting the base64 data from the return value of the `toDataURL()` call.

Comment: The base64 string is an encoding of the image file. If you used toDataURL() without the mime type, the image file format will be as a compressed png 32Bit image, or you can get a jpeg with `toDataURL("image/jpeg", quality)` where quality is a value 0 - 1. The image type should be in the data url eg `"image/png;base64,"` To get the pixels at the server you will need to decode the image file using a png or jpeg decoder.  Personally you should consider doing the image processing client side, especially for simple stuff like average color

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64

import numpy as np
import cv2

base64_string = "INSERT BASE64 HERE"
decoded = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
buffer = np.fromstring(decoded, np.float32)
image_array = cv2.imdecode(buffer, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("img", image_array)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The base64 string is decoded and then np.fromstring converts the decoded string to an array. Finally cv2.imdecode decodes the NumPy array to convert to image format.

Comment: Using different strings doesn't work, i get the "string size must be a multiple of element size" error from ```buffer = np.fromstring(decoded, np.float32)```. I guess that was a lucky image, because most images don't work, for example: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAf0lEQVQ4T+2U3QnAIAyEL/uI4AZu7gqKA6Wk1Bfxlwak0Lznkrt8hJiZoVj0C75O88MZxhjhnENNFREh5wxjTDOeoWVpbtUI3e0MZYiaYNlYVTClBGttF68tyzO7MuWMYH1t7z1CCPvYlI4WPr3DnLF8h/1APvvHyxuqC67+tQtTHHnFkfTgdAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: That's odd, because when I plugged in the aforementioned string it output the an image with the number '7'.

Comment: base64_string = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAf0lEQVQ4T+2U3QnAIAyEL/uI4AZu7gqKA6Wk1Bfxlwak0Lznkrt8hJiZoVj0C75O88MZxhjhnENNFREh5wxjTDOeoWVpbtUI3e0MZYiaYNlYVTClBGttF68tyzO7MuWMYH1t7z1CCPvYlI4WPr3DnLF8h/1APvvHyxuqC67+tQtTHHnFkfTgdAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

Comment: I will try updating my numpy version, maybe that's causing the issue :?